# Delays on Dell Servers?

Tags: hardware, dell

Is anyone else experiencing delays in getting orders for servers fulfilled from Dell?  We ordered some servers in late November of 2009 and got an estimated ship date of early Dec.  That date has steadily slipped and they can no longer give us ANY estimate on when the machines will ship.

Our experience with Dell in the past has been much different/better, but this is very concerning... particularily given that they have no estimate on when it will ship.

Curious if others are seeing this also or if it's limited to this one order.

Answer (score 1):

December is a nightmare for Dell, because of all the xmas desktop business. Perfectly normal.

I'd still call and scream at them, but that's just because I like calling and screaming.

Comment: Yup, they always get destroyed at this time.  We order extra parts for our DCs in October/early November in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

Also note that Dell's fiscal end of quarter trails the calendar year by one month (specifically Jan 31, Apr 30, July 31, Oct 31.)  If you are buying servers in any quantity, that's when you can get the best deals. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you completing your purchases through the Dell Gold team? While I haven't purchased server hardware I've bought a fair amount of machines during December, some being very custom configured developer rigs and with my contact was able to get me them delivered in a few business days.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced major delays getting i7 workstations and laptops through Dell (I order roughly $100k/yr in equipment from them) but I always get my "Business" equipment (things from the enterprise/business end) amazingly fast. My last Powerconnect/Poweredge order was in late November and I received them (quad xeons) in about 3-4 days.

In regard to above, I've been waiting 2 1/2 months for a few i7 laptops and desktops. The dates keep getting pushed back, I've read that Dell is low on stock of i7 processors.

Have you spoken to your rep, if you have one?

Comment: Yes, we have a rep and have taled to him...and his manager.  We're waiting on a single server.  It's really the delays that are upsetting, but rather their inability to tell me WHEN It will ship.  Never experienced this before with them.